# Mixing different reference types in one collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references, soft-references, phantom-reference

`SoftReference`, `WeakReference`, `PhantomReference` may be used to customize the process of garbage collection. All of them extend `Reference<T>` therefore it is possible to mix them in single collection. Hard references (most common ones) do no extend `Reference<T>` therefore it is not possible to mix hard and other types of references in one collection. Am I right and we should put `CustomReference<T> extends Reference<T>` to the collection in order to achieve the desired result of mixing all types of object links in single collection (`Collection<Reference<T>>`)?

UPDATE: So when writing [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) I've found that it is not possible to extend `Reference<T>` in a usual way (constructor is package-local).

So the question now updates to the following: can I with *single* collection class create cache which always holds some objects (say 10) and the others are reclaimed by GC when memory not allows? Is there any other means to do this except providing custom wrappers for hard and soft references and storing them in the collection?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking.  The answer's probably 'yes, if you want to'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `Reference<T>` most not (and can not) be subclassed directly, according to [its JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html):

> Because reference objects are implemented in close cooperation with the garbage collector, this class may not be subclassed directly.

As such you won't be able to easily (i.e. without ugly `instanceof` + casting) handle both soft/weak/phantom references *and* normal references in the same `Collection`.

You could write a wrapper that *either* uses two separate `Collection` objects to handle normal and soft/weak/phantom references *or* that puts them all into the same `Collection<Object>` and uses the appropriate `instanceof` checks with casts to differentiate the objects.

Comment: What should I do if I dont like both? :)

Comment: A variation would be to write a `MyReference<T>` wrapper that holds *either* a `Reference<T>` *or* a `T` itself. You could even write it in a way that allows "toggling" between soft/weak/strong references during its lifetime (and possibly phantom, but that would be a one-way path).

Comment: the last your suggestion is already implemented :) I thought there is a better way. It seems we dont have a lot of options. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You use a **SoftReference** when you want the referenced object to stay alive until the host process is running low on memory. The object will not be eligible for collection until the collector needs to free memory. Loosely stated, binding a SoftReference means, "Pin the object until you can't anymore."

By contrast, use a **WeakReference** when you don't want to influence the referenced object's lifetime; you merely want to make a separate assertion about the referenced object, so long as it remains alive. The object's eligibility for collection is not influenced by the presence of bound WeakReferences. Something like a an external mapping from object instance to related property, where the property need only be recorded so long as the related object is alive, is a good use for WeakReferences and WeakHashMap.

The last one -- **PhantomReference** -- is harder to characterize. Like WeakReference, such a bound PhantomReference exerts no influence on the referenced object's lifetime. But unlike the other reference types, one can't even dereference a PhantomReference. In a sense, it doesn't point to the thing it points to, as far as callers can tell. It merely allows one to associate some related data with the referenced object -- data that can later be inspected and acted upon when the PhantomReference gets queued in its related ReferenceQueue. Normally one derives a type from PhantomReference and includes some additional data in that derived type. Unfortunately, there's some downcasting involved to make use of such a derived type.

more info in this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html

Added one more link 
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html

Comment: Yes, I can read javadoc too. :) What happens when you define your own type of reference?

Comment: A good summary of the difference reference types, but it doesn't really answer the question.